# python image taken date and time

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, exif

I'm trying to create an array that contains the filenames of all images in a folder in the first column and the "time taken" of the image in the second column. This time should be in hh:mm:ss:msmsms (or hhmmssmsmsms), where "ms" is milliseconds.

I found a piece of code that uses the Pillow library with the to pull the EXIFTAG data of the image. I realize that I would need the DateTimeOriginal and SubsecTimeOriginal tags to get the data I want.
Now the problem is that I just don't understand how the code bellow pulls the data from the image and how I would be able to create the desired array. If anyone knows how the .ExifTags and ._getexif() modules work, some explanation would be appreciated.

code:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS

file_path = 'IMG_20200528_125319.jpg'

results = {}
i = Image.open(file_path)
info = i._getexif()
for tag, value in info.items():
    decoded = TAGS.get(tag, tag)
    results[decoded] = value

print results
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? You can get the DateTimeOriginal like this `DTO = info[36867]` and the subsection field with `SSTO = info[37521]`

Comment: `exiftool` may help you debug, try `exiftool -p '$filename $DateTimeOriginal $SubSecTimeOriginal' *.jpg`

Comment: When I define the SSTO = info[37521] and try to print it, I get the error "KeyError: 37521". I think the problem might be that the SubsecTimeOriginal just isn't included in the Exif of the images taken with the OpenCamera app on Samsung Note4.

Comment: `exiftool` example above will tell you that immediately.

Comment: Ok, I was finnaly able to make it work, thanks for the exiftool tip. Sadly I think the SubsecTime tag is missing the picture. I also compared it to an image made by a DSLR Canon camera which has the tag, but the value is 00. I suppose the tag is there but the value is always 00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly the info I was looking for is not in the exif tags of the picture. See Mark Setchell's comments.